# "On [Subject]" vs. "Of [Subject]" in Titles

Tags: word-usage

I see "On" and "Of" in the titles of many essays, and was wondering what the difference between the two is. For example, what is the difference between, "On Sadness" and "Of Sadness"? "On Grief" vs "Of Grief"?

Comment: "Of" is archaic.